# Android Google API logging in

Tags: android, authentication, google-api, onactivityresult

I'm experiencing a lot of problems with logging in into Google API.
I've seen many possible implementations, and not one of them really seems to work.

## Here is #1 from [here](https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html):

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d("MA", "onConnected");
    mSignInOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mSignInOut.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.signOut));
    mSignInOut.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.signOutButton));
    mLoggedInMessage.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.loggedInMessage) + " " + getUsername() + "!");
}



protected boolean isSignedIn() {
    return (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
}

public void signInOut() {
    if(isSignedIn()) {
        Log.d("MA", "signinout: signing out");
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        onLoggedOut();
    } else {
        Log.d("MA", "signinout: signing in");
        mSignInClicked = true;
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RQC_SIGN_IN) {
        mResolvingError = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() &&
                    !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (mResolvingError) {
        // Already attempting to resolve an error.
        return;
    } else if (result.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mResolvingError = true;
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, RQC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // There was an error with the resolution intent. Try again.
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    } else {
        // Show dialog using GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()
        showErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode());
        mResolvingError = true;
    }
}

// The rest of this code is all about building the error dialog

/* Creates a dialog for an error message */
private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {
    // Create a fragment for the error dialog
    ErrorDialogFragment dialogFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
    // Pass the error that should be displayed
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("DIALOG_ERROR", errorCode);
    dialogFragment.setArguments(args);
    dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "errordialog");
}

/* Called from ErrorDialogFragment when the dialog is dismissed. */
public void onDialogDismissed() {
    mResolvingError = false;
}

/* A fragment to display an error dialog */
public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public ErrorDialogFragment() { }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the error code and retrieve the appropriate dialog
        int errorCode = this.getArguments().getInt("DIALOG_ERROR");
        return GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode,
                this.getActivity(), RQC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).onDialogDismissed();
    }
}
```

The problem here is, when I sign out and in again after app start the UI doesn't change/onConnected isn't called, but when I switch the activity so it tries to connect again, it immediately calls onConnected. It worked when I put `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` into the top of `onActivityResult`, but then it connects and after successfull connection he seems to try again to connect, but right before I would choose an account the window disappears.
EDIT: Also it doesn't show any error dialog when something went wrong.

## Number 2 is quite the same but with different `onActivityResult` and `onConnectionFailed` methods, got it from [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == RQC_SIGN_IN) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mResolvingError = false;
        Log.d("MA", "resultCode: " + resultCode);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        } else {
            Log.d("MA", "onActivityResult, resultCode != -1");
            BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(this, requestCode, resultCode, R.string.signin_other_error);
        }
    }
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // If the sign in button was clicked or if auto sign-in is enabled,
    // launch the sign-in flow
    Log.d("BFA", "onConnectionFailed, connectionresult: " + result.getErrorCode());
    if (mResolvingError) {
        Log.d("BFA", "Already attempting to resolve an error.");
        // Already attempting to resolve an error.
        return;
    }
    if (mSignInClicked || mAutoLogin) {
        mResolvingError = true;
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mAutoLogin = false;
        if (!BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this, mGoogleApiClient, result,
                RQC_SIGN_IN, getString(R.string.signin_other_error))) {
            Log.d("MA", "resolveConnectionFailure false");
            mResolvingError = false;
        }
    }
}
```

With this approach i receive an error message after choosing an account, but getting logged in afterwards nevertheless.

Somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found the mistake, of course there where I would have searched at last.

It was in the creation of the `Builder`, I used `enableAutoManage()` and so it apparently duplicated the actions I wanted to do anyway. Cut it out and worked, used an approach similar to #2.